# Is server-side access control sufficient or should I encrypt querystrings

Tags: encryption

I've got an ASP Classic system that passes around sequential ids corresponding to keys in the database.

I had gotten an encryption module (chilkat, an activex control) that I was using to encrypt and decrypt entire querystrings.

However, since I do validate a user's right to access a particular resource (noted by an ID on the querystring), do I still need to do URL encryption? Would my site pass a security audit in this case?

(or more importantly, should I continue doing both or is access control sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use non-sequential identifier (you can then log / monitor for attempts to access non-existent files for example) however by no means essential and its unlikely to fail an audit provided the role / authorization scheme you have in place is robust. You want to be sure you have full coverage of authorisation checks on access to "things".

You also need to ensure that the userId can't be altered to a different user. It is usually better to send the user a session token that is random and link that to a user session and identity / authorisation behind the scenes.

Testing your authorisation should be part of your regression cycle before every release and can readily be automated by the likes of HtmlUnit ( http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ ) or Selenium ( http://www.seleniumhq.org/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Encryption makes sense only if:

- The encrypted value may come under the eyes of entities/people who should be denied knowledge of the value.
- Systems which must process the value *can* decrypt it.

In your case, if you encrypt client-side, then this must be to protect *against* the server itself. However, if the server must be able to understand the data, in order to enforce filters, then the server must be able to decrypt it. Therefore, such encryption *cannot* protect the data against the server. The conclusion is that the encryption you are describing does not make sense: it provides no useful security property.

(Well, you might encrypt for another reason: to protect against eavesdropping in transit between client and server. But that would apply only if you do something stupid, namely not using SSL. The solution for stupid things is to stop doing them.)